# Disable corkscrew for local addresses

Tags: ssh, local, http-proxy

I have a question about Corkscrew, which i use to get SSH to work through HTTP-proxy.
SSH is working fine to external hosts but not for local hosts. How can i disable 
SSH to connect to local servers over HTTP-Proxy? I guess this is the problem why i get:

```
root@V01-XXXX:~# ssh root@172.XX.XX.8
Proxy could not open connnection to 172.XX.XX.8:  Forbidden
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

My /etc/ssh/ssh_config file contains:

```
Host *
ProxyCommand /usr/bin/corkscrew proxy.ezorg.nl 8080 %h %p
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

First of all you may consider putting the configuration in `~/.ssh/config` instead of /etc/ssh/ssh_config.

To just use corkscrew for some specific Hosts don't use the asterisk but list the specific hosts instead, like:

```
Host external.com example.com
ProxyCommand /usr/bin/corkscrew proxy.ezorg.nl 8080 %h %p
```

You can also negate a pattern to only set the proxy command if you connect to a specific host.

```
Host * !192.168.0.? !*.local 
ProxyCommand /usr/bin/corkscrew proxy.ezorg.nl 8080 %h %p
```

will match for all hosts except hosts in 192.168.0.0/24 and hosts within the .local TLD

Comment: could you please help me with - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600830/ssh-ing-to-remote-server-from-behind-a-proxy

Answer (score 2):

You can add lines to your `ssh_config` to disable use of the proxy for certain hosts.  Something like:

```
Host *.local host1 host2 host3
    ProxyCommand none
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for the help. On wheezy it didn't resolve `localhost` (I can't find why), but worked perfectly with:

```
Host 127.0.0.1
ProxyCommand none

Host *
ProxyCommand /usr/bin/corkscrew <proxy> <proxyport> %h %p
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding @Michael Slade's answer, the following in your `.ssh/config` works:

```
Host localhost
ProxyCommand none

Host *
ProxyCommand corkscrew proxy.com ....
```

Only the first occurrence of a parameter is read by `ssh`.